# How can I synchronize the viewport cameras across different workspaces?

Tags: modeling, interface

Its really annoying that the camera snaps back to the previous layout/modeling view when you switch between those two. How can I make it just maintain 1 camera view and not have a separate camera for each different view/tab?

Comment: Hi :). Our hero [@Crantizs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/32374/crantisz) made a free addon for this. You can download it here: https://m-soluyanov.gumroad.com/l/afoty

Comment: Modeling Layout it's just Edit mode with an extra step, you can switch to edit mode using TAB on your keyboard without leaving the Default Layout

Comment: Hello ! I took the liberty to generalize your question to possibly attract more answer-ers. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it. Cheers